# Natural Logarithm and Euler's Number

Tags: limits, exponential-function

Why is $\log_e(x)'=\ln(x)'= 1/x$? how to prove the differentiation rule.
ofc that means also $\int(1/x)dx=\ln(x) + c$

I think that the derivative of the $\ln$ of a variable with respect to the variable being 1/x is an axiom to prove that the limit of

$(1 + 1/(ax))^{bx}$ as $x \to \infty$  is $e^{b/a}$

How to prove one without using the other and any theorem following from them ?

Or at least can we prove one of them without the other and the other should follow?

Comment: Do you have access to the theorem which tells you something about the derivative of the inverse function? I.e. using that $\ln(x)$ is the inverse of $\exp(x)$ (and that $\exp'(x)=\exp(x)$).

Comment: Euler's constant $\gamma \approx 0.577...$ is something different from $e \approx 2.718...$.

Comment: @JeanMarie People often to refer to $e$ as Euler's constant too. Besides, the context makes it clear which is being referred to.

Comment: "I think... is an axiom". Actually, all of these and many others are actually equivalent *definitions* (not axioms) since given any one of them, you can prove the other. However, you'll need to tell us what your definitions are. How do you define $\ln(x)$? How do you define $e^x$?

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt: I think $\mathrm e$ is referred to as *Euler's number*, not ‘Euler's constant’.

Comment: @Bernard *\*shrugs\** I believe there exists a similar comment thread, long long ago... not that I'd care to find it. But out of your comment and Jean Marie's, I've edited the title to avoid confusion.

Comment: You are using what you want to prove.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to define $\ln(x)$ or $e$ in numerous different ways, such that they don't have to depend on each other. So too can you prove that $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\ln(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ or $\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^x=e$, though the method may depend on how you've defined each construct.

**@Bernard**'s answer covers the case that $\ln(x):=y$ such that $x=e^y$. Likewise, **@Chris Custer**'s answer covers the case that $\ln(x):=\int_1^x\frac{1}t\,\mathrm{d}t$. For completeness, there's a few other ways you can define $\ln(x)$.

**Limit Definition**

If $\ln(x):=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{x^h-1}{h}$, then:

$$\begin{aligned}\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\ln(x)
&=\lim_{g\to0}\frac{\lim_{h\to0}\frac{(x+g)^h-1}{h}-\lim_{h\to0}\frac{x^h-1}{h}}{g}
\\\text{Definition of derivative.}&
\\&=\lim_{g\to0}\lim_{h\to0}\frac{(x+g)^h-1-x^h+1}{hg}
\\\text{Multiply through by $h$.}&
\\&=\lim_{g\to0}\lim_{h\to0}\frac{x^h(\frac{g}{x}+1)^h-x^h}{hg}
\\\text{Put in form $(z+1)^\alpha$.}&
\\&=\lim_{g\to0}\lim_{h\to0}\frac{x^h\left[1+h\frac{g}{x}+\binom{h}{2}\frac{g^2}{x^2}+\ldots\right]-x^h}{hg}
\\\text{Binomial Series.}&
\\&=\lim_{g\to0}\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\color{red}{\not}{x^h}+hgx^{h-1}+\binom{h}{2}g^2x^{h-2}+\ldots-\color{red}{\not}{x^h}}{hg}
\\\text{Cancel terms.}&
\\&=\lim_{g\to0}\lim_{h\to0}\left[x^{h-1}+hg(\ldots)\right]
\\\text{Factor $h$ and $g$.}&
\\&=x^{-1}
\end{aligned}$$

You may ask how we'd calculate $y=x^{0.0\ldots01}$ without logarithms. We can do it with the Newton-Raphson method, finding the roots of $y^{100\ldots0}-x=0$. We can use similar methods to compute $x^r$ for rational $r$.

**Series Definition**

We can also define $\ln(x)$ by its Taylor series. In this case, its derivative is, for $0<x<2$:

$$\begin{aligned}
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\ln(x)
&=\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left(-\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{(1-x)^n}{n}\right)
\\&=-\left(\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{n(1-x)^{n-1}\cdot(-1)}{n}\right)
\\\text{Differentiate each term.}&
\\&=\sum_{n\geq1}(1-x)^{n-1}
\\\text{Cancelled $n$ and $-1$.}&
\\&=\frac{1}{1-(1-x)}
\\\text{Limit of geometric series.}&
\\&=\frac{1}{x}
\end{aligned}
$$

Whether it's really justified to differentiate an infinite series is a bit hand-wavey, I'll admit but I think this answer gives a fairly good feel for how you can show that $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\ln(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ with alternative definitions. In fact we haven't used $e$ once. We can probaly be able to prove the derivative with other means too. [This Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1341958/proof-of-the-derivative-of-lnx) gives some ways of proving it.

Comment: The problem I have is that we use lns property of ln(x)'=1/x to calculate (1 + 1/x)^x as x aproaches inf. And we use e=that limit to prove that ln(x)'=1/x integrals inverse functions et al are implicitly using the above when e^x'=e'x then ln(x)'=1/x

Comment: @GeorgeNtoulos If you mean to say that the definitions are circular, then that's what I've been trying to show isn't necessarily true. We can chose numerous different ways of defining $e^x$ and $\ln(x)$ such that we are doing logically sound steps. Case in point, we could define $e=\sum_{n\geq0}\frac{1}{n!}$.

Comment: We also don't have to use $\ln$ at all in calculating $\lim_{x\to+\infty}(1+1/x)^x$. We can show that it converges to a finite value and define that value as $e$.

Comment: The Mathematics beats me

Comment: @GeorgeNtoulos You'll get there, if you stick at it. You're clearly asking the right questions. It's a good thing to question the definitions of particular mathematical constructs, but in this case, $\ln$ and $e$ are very well established so they've got quite a solid framework  :)

Comment: The limit can be shown to be $e $ , where $e^x $ and $lnx $ are inverses, without the use of the derivative. ..

Comment: @ChrisCuster Yeah, of course. What's your point?

Comment: @Jam Just trying to answer the original question...

Comment: I am studying Economics 4rth year. I quitte enjoy mathematics.

Answer (score 3):

It certainly is not an axiom.

If $\ln$ is defined as the inverse of the exponential function (which is its own derivative):
$$y=\ln x\quad(x>0)\overset{\text{def}}{\iff} x=\mathrm e^y,$$
then
$$(\ln)'(x)=\frac 1{(\mathrm e^y)'}=\frac 1{\mathrm e^y}=\frac 1x.$$

Comment: You used what you want to prove.

Comment: @GeorgeNtoulos: How that?

Comment: You are using e. Isn't what you said implicit I said  to prove one without using the other and any theorem following from them !

Comment: This depends on the definition you have for the exponential. The standard definition is it's the sum of the power series $\;1+x+\dfrac{x^2}2+\dots+\dfrac{x^n}{n!}+\dotsm$. Almost equivalent: you can say it is the solution of the differential equation $y'=y$ with initial condition $y(0)=1$.

Comment: 1st question how do you do math quotients and exponents.

Comment: 1st question how do you do math namely quotients and exponents? The problem I have is that we use lns property of ln(x)'=1/x to calculate (1 + 1/x)^x as x aproaches inf. And we use e=that limit to prove that ln(x)'=1/x integrals inverse functions et al are implicitly using the above when e^x'=e'x then ln(x)'=1/x

Comment: I don't understand your first question: what's `doing math, namely quotients and exponents`?

Comment: Formating formulas

Comment: Oh! I see. Just type the LaTeX code (the system is MathJax, but in most cases it's simple LaTeX code), between `$ ... $` for inline maths, between `$$ ... $$` for displayed formulae, or one of the amsmath environments for multiline displayed environments. For instance $a:b$ as a true fraction is coded `\frac{a}{b}` and so on. I think  there are tutorials on this site.

Answer (score 0):

That $(\ln x)'=\frac1x$ follows from the definition of  $\ln x$ and the fundamental theorem of calculus. ..
$\ln x=\int_1^x \frac 1t dt$ by definition. ..

Comment: From the way the OP has posed the question, it looks like they aren't taking $\ln(x)=\int_1^x\frac1t~\mathrm dt$ by definition.