# derivation of the logarithm by hands, not by formula table

Tags: derivatives, logarithms

I trying to find any good example of derivation of $\lg (x)$ from the very begining.
I know that $(\lg (x))' = \frac{1}{x}$ but WHY?
I cannot get the same answer by calculating it by my hands.

$$
\lim_ {h \to 0} \dfrac{\lg (x+h) - \lg (x)}{h} 
$$

How should i solve this limit?

Comment: Try to use sandwich theorem.

Comment: This is often shown with the inverse function theorem: Since $\exp$ is differentiable its inverse function $\log$ is also differentiable and $\log'(x) = \frac{1}{\exp'(\log(x))} = \frac{1}{x}.$ This however doesn't answer the question how to see this using only the difference quotient alone.

Comment: Are you asking for a logarithm with base $10$, or base $e$ ($\ln$)? Anyway, all logarithms are equal with multiplication by a constant (e.g. $\log_{10} (x) = \ln(x) \cdot \frac{1}{\ln 10}$... And then you can use the fact you've stated for the derivative of $\ln$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Continuing from your work, we can use logarithm rules, and get

$$ 
\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{1}{h} \ln \left ({\frac{x+h}{x}} \right ) = \ln \left ( 1 + \frac{h}{x} \right )^\frac{1}{h}
$$

We can do a switch of variables, e.g. $k = \frac{1}{h}$ and get

$$
\lim_{k \to \infty} \ln \left (1 + \frac{1}{kx} \right )^k
$$

You can see that whats inside the $\ln$ approaches $e^{\frac{1}{x}}$. Therefore,
$$ (\ln x)' = \ln e^{\frac{1}{x}} = \frac{1}{x}$$

Anyway, this is a "crude" way to prove the derivative of $\ln$. For the derivative of any logarithm with a different base, simply note that
$$ \log_a (x) = \ln(x) \cdot \frac{1}{\ln a} $$

Finally, also check out [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1341958/proof-of-the-derivative-of-lnx).

Comment: Nice. This is what i needed for.

Answer (score 1):

You can grind through it like this:

$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\ln(x+h)-\ln (x)}{h} = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{\ln\left(\frac{x+h}{x}\right)}{h}  $$

$$=\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{\ln\left(1+\frac{h}{x}\right)}{h} = 
 \lim_{h\to 0} \ln\left(\exp\left( \frac{\ln\left(1+\frac{h}{x}\right)}{h}\right)\right)$$

$$= \lim_{h\to 0} \ln\left( \left(1+\frac{x}{h}\right)^{1/h}\right).  $$

Now substitute $y =x/h$, so when $h\to 0$, then $y\to \infty.$  Also $h = x/y$.  The above

$$ = \lim_{y\to \infty} \ln\left( \left(1+\frac{1}{y}\right)^{\frac{y}{x}}\right). $$

Since the (or one) definition of $e$ is $e=\lim_{y\to \infty} \left(1+\frac{1}{y}\right)^y,$  and since $\ln x$ is continuous, we have

$$= \ln\left( \left(\lim_{y\to \infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{y}\right)^y\right)^{1/x}\right)=\ln e^{1/x} = \frac{1}{x}.   $$

Answer (score 0):

$\log_{10}(x)=\frac1{\ln 10}\ln x$, therefore $\log_{10}'(x)=\frac1{x\ln 10}$ by what you've already established for $\ln$. If you *haven't* established what the derivative of $\ln$ is, apply identity $(f^{-1})'=\frac1{f'\circ f^{-1}}$ to $f(x)=\exp(x)$, obtaining $$\ln'(x)=\frac1{\exp'(\ln x)}=\frac1{\exp(\ln x)}=\frac1x.$$